# call method from the same class that looks like

Tags: ios, objective-c

call method from the same class that looks like

```
-(void)functionA:(TemplateController *)sender    ??
```

1. It is already defined in the .h.
2. Usually I would do something like `[self functionA];` but I am getting an error of instance method not found.

Comment: [self functionA:sender]; or [self functionA];?

Comment: **[self functionA]** It expected to get an error , If you are no need to deal with the parameter then call the method like this **[self functionA:nil];**

Comment: Please use the correct terminology: a "method" is *declared* in the header .h and *defined* (which means implemented) in the module .m file. While most people accepting the phrase "call a method", it is strictly: "*send* a *message* to a *receiver*".

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)functionA:(TemplateController *)sender
```

Is a method named `functionA:`, which expects a parameter of type `TemplateController`

While you are not passing any parameter to it `[self functionA]`.

It should be something like this

```
[self functionA:templateControllerObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has an Parameter.

```
-(void)functionA:(TemplateController *)sender
```

Paramter is TemplateController so without passing this parameter. this method not being called.

you are not passing the parameter so it gives an error.

```
[self FunctionA];
```

This is wrong way.

So pass the parameter Like this

```
[self functionA:templateControllerObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about function syntax in objective-c

`- (type_r) abc:(type1)x cde:(type2)y def:(type3)z`

is an instance method (using it requires creation of an object) whose name is `abc:cde:def:`, which returns something of type type_r, receives three arguments x, y and z, of types type1, type2 and type 3 respectively.

To call it, you say
`class_name obj = [[class_name alloc] init];

[obj abc:x1 cde:y1 def:z1];`

It is like doing this in c++:
`class_name obj = new class_name();

obj.func_name(x1, y1, z1);`

If there was a '+' instead of '-' at the beginning, this would mean it is a class method and it is supposed to be called using just the class name
`[class_name abc:x1 cde:y1 def:z1];`

Secondly, functions are not 'implemented' in header files. They are just 'declared' as a directive to the compiler that don't worry, you will find the implementation of this function at the linking time.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `-(void)functionA:(TemplateController *)sender`, sender is a parameter to the method.So when you call `functionA` method you should specify the parameter even though parameter is `nil`, ie `[self functionA:nil]`. If you don't need any parameter to be passed you should change your method as `-(void)functionA`, then you can call it as `[self functionA]`.